Why does my containerized API fail to find a relative path which I've confirmed is correct?
I'm running a FastAPI app in a Docker container. For the app to work it needs access to its secrets, which are in a folder inside the app (for local development only), however, it can't find the secrets directory.
My file structure inside the container's working directory is the following:
project/
├── app/
│   └── secrets/
│       └── LOCAL_DEV/
├── environments/
│   └── LOCAL_DEV/
└── main.py

The working directory is set as "project", and adding the following debug statement:
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent
logger.debug(f"Current base directory: {BASE_DIR}")

Confirms that the current directory is "/project", however, when it's time to extract the secrets, the program fails with:
directory "app/secrets/LOCAL_DEV" does not exist
Everything runs fine when running it outside of the container, what am I missing here?
EDIT: Mentioning that I've tried "project/app/secrets/LOCAL_DEV" instead and it also doesn't work.

Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  What is in your Dockerfile?  Are you hiding any of that filesystem content with volume mounts?  Can you provide the file location via an environment variable or a similar option, without hard-coding a path in your application?

@DavidMaze it turned out to be a case sensitivity issue having to do with the paths turning lowercase at some point, I fixed it.

It turned out to be a case sensitivity issue. At a point in the code the name of the folder turns into "local_dev", which is fine running it locally on Windows since paths are not case sensitive, but causes an error on Linux.
